# Mysql delete multiple tables with left join in one statement caused FK violation

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Mysql delete multiple tables with left join in one statement caused FK violation. For example,

```
Student       StudentDetail      
--------      ------------------------------
id, name      studentId, birthday, address

100 John       100      1/1/1982   A1
200 Scott      200      1/1/1978   A2
300 Tiger      300      1/1/1988   A3

FullTimeStudent
------------------
studentId, program

200        P1
```

The studentId column of StudentDetail and FullTimeStudent is FK referencing to the id column of Student table.

Delete student with id=200

```
delete t0, t2, t1 from StudentDetail t1
LEFT join FullTimeStudent t2 on (t1.studentId=t2.studentId) 
LEFT join Student t0 on (t1.studentId=t0.id) where t0.id=200;
```

Error: Foreign key constraint violation.

IF changing the left join to inner join, the deletion is successful. What is wrong with left join?

But no difference between left and inner join for selection.

```
select t0.id, t2.studentId, t1.studentId from StudentDetail t1
LEFT join FullTimeStudent t2 on (t1.studentId=t2.studentId) 
LEFT join Student t0 on (t1.studentId=t0.id) where t0.id=100;
```

Returns one row.

Comment: Can You show us Your foreign keys, e.g. by "show create table ..."

Comment: @Nick Only InnoDB implements foreign key constraints, so they must be.

Comment: You should configure your foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then you just need to delete from the `Student` table, and it will automatically delete the related rows in the other tables.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please act on [mcve]. And in it show that you are running each update/query from the same start state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables
>   for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might
>   process tables in an order that differs from that of their
>   parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls
>   back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the
>   ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables
>   to be modified accordingly.

As the manual (and @Barmar) says, the way to work around this is to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your constraints e.g. in `FullTimeStudent` and `StudentDetail` use:

```
FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES Student(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Mysql has more work to do on this one. The delete statement should be an atomic operation.

Comment: @Sunnyday yes - another thing to add to their long list. I guess the argument is that if you want everything you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the `LEFT JOIN` in the wrong order. The first table should be the master table, and you should then join with the detail tables.

```
DELETE t0, t1, t2
FROM Student t0
LEFT JOIN FullTimeStudent t1 ON t1.studentID = t0.id
LEFT JOIN StudentDetail t2 ON t2.studentID = t0.id
WHERE t0.id = 200
```

However, the proper design is to use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option in your foreign key constraints. Then you just have to delete from the master table, and the related rows will be deleted automatically.

```
DELETE FROM Student
WHERE id = 200
```

Comment: Tried the delete statement(make the master table as the first table in joins), FK violation still occurs.

Comment: See the other answer. The optimizer might choose to do the deletes in the wrong order.